# Strange error in status reports en unable to safe my taxonomy term url-alias

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8, path-aliases

When I go to `admin/reports/status` I see this error (see image).

Also I am unable to safe my taxonomy term url-alias? What does this error mean and how can I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore this.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2661178 and the core issue linked there for details.

Nothing is broken, the entity definition change tracking just gets a bit confused.